# Order of dictionary keys when performing conditional list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

In Python 3.10, I am aware that a dictionary preserves insertion order. However when performing conditional list comprehensions, can this order still be guaranteed?

For example, given:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['a'] = 1
my_dict['b'] = 2
my_dict['c'] = 3
my_dict['d'] = 4
```

Can one **guarantee** that either (option A):

```
print([k for k in my_dict.keys() if k not in ['c']])
```

or (option B):

```
print([k for k in (my_dict.keys() - {'c'})])
```

will *always* return:

```
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: What does a dict comprehension have to do with dicts specifically? Think about this: would the order of the resulting list be the same if you swapped my_dict.keys() with ["bla", "blu", "ble"] ?

Comment: @Larry, okay fair question. I don't know. Can it be guaranteed that the order will remain in your example?

Comment: The variable substituted for each element of the iterable to the right of the "for" clause is substituted in the order in which elements occur in the iterable, and the expression to the left of the "for" clause is processed after substitution and filtering by the "if" clause. So yes, in both our examples, the order remains the same. This behavior directly follows from what is described under "List comprehension" in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you, @Larry. That makes it clear.

Comment: Hmmm, @Larry, actually, I don't see the same results. If I do this, ```print([k for k in (my_dict.keys() - {'a'})])``` I get ```['c', 'b', 'd']``` and NOT ```['b', 'c', 'd']``` as I would expect.

Comment: That is because your source iterable is not a dict. It is a dict_keys object. If you want the keys, just iterate over the dict. Dicts are a sequence of their own keys. EDIT: this also has nothing to do with list comprehensions. If you print my_dict.keys() by itself, you will probably also find that insertion order is not reflected in the result.

Comment: @Larry If iterating over `dict` *vs* `dict.keys()` could give different results, that would be a serious bug. This is true for any version of Python, since the current order will always be *stable*, even if it doesn't match the insertion order. In Python 3, the `keys()` method [provides a dynamic view of the dictionary's entries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), so it is *guaranteed* to directly reflect the current state of the dict. The views themselves may be "set-like", but that does not imply they are unordered (or independently ordered).

Comment: The two examples in the question are certainly *not* guaranteed to give the same results. This is because the first one iterates over `my_dict.keys()`, which is guaranteed to have a stable order; whereas the second iterates over `my_dict.keys() - {'c'}`, which has no guaranteed order, since it evaluates to a `set`, rather than a view/list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over `dict` or `dict.keys()` should give the same results for any version of Python, since the language guarantees the current order will always be *stable*, even if it doesn't necessarily match the insertion order. In Python 3, the `keys()` method [provides a dynamic view of the dictionary's entries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), so it will directly reflect the current state of the dict. The views themselves may be "set-like", but that does not imply they are unordered (or independently ordered).

The problem with the examples in the question is that they don't compare like with like. The `keys()` method returns a `view` (or a `list` in earlier versions), whereas `keys() - {'a'}` evaluates to a `set` (i.e. an object with no guaranteed order). So it is safe to assume option A will always give the same results, but not option B.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, I understand now.

Answer (score -1):

I think the short answer is yes, the "preserves insertion order" clause gives you a proper order of keys whenever you go through them (be it via `for k in my_dict` or `my_dict.keys()`), and together with the one that @Larry pointed out gives you what you ask for.

However the downwotes on this question are probably due to the fact that if you need an answer to this question for a coding problem, you should either learn more about list comprehensions or just rethink your solution and sort the keys based on insertion order or whatever way of **guaranteing** you'd imagine

Comment: But, ```print([k for k in (my_dict.keys() - {'a'})])``` I get ```['c', 'b', 'd']``` and NOT ```['b', 'c', 'd']``` so it seems the answer, at least for option B, is not yes.

Comment: well the question was "... that either ..." and the answer is yes. If the question was "which of the following options ... ?" then the answer would probably give you the exact option

Comment: @handlist The answer is actually correct. However, in your example, you are not carrying out an operation which reflects the dict's order, and thus your code is irrelevant to your own question. It is the `.keys()` method which returns an object whose element order does not reflect that of the dictionary, the list comprehension still processes elements in an iterable in their original order, including those in a dict.

Comment: @Larry, thank you, this was the key point I was missing "It is the ```.keys()``` method which returns an object whose element order does not reflect that of the dictionary". Also, in that case, the answer is not correct as EP says order is preserved by "... or ```my_dict.keys()```"

Comment: @handlist In the discussion below your answer, I have already answered this, along with a suggestion of what to do.

Comment: @handlist The claim that the `keys()` method "returns an object whose element order does not reflect that of the dictionary" is wrong for all versions of Python. The language has always guaranteed that the order of the keys (and values) is stable, even if earlier versions did not specify what the particular order would be. The problem here is that you aren't comparing like with like. The `keys()` method returns a `view` (or a `list` in earlier versions), whereas `keys() - {'a'}` evaluates to a `set` (i.e. an object with no guaranteed order). So your option A is safe, but option B is not.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you very much for the explaination, that makes it very clear. If you would like to combine your two comments into an answer I would be very happy to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @ekhumoro You are absolutely right! Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @handlist Glad to be of some help. I have now summarised my comments in an answer.